# ng-animate multiple table rows do not animate

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-animate

I'm attempting to hilight when items appear in a table.  There may be 2, 3, or more items that appear at the same time.  However, `ng-animate` does **not** appear to handle this correctly.

In the following fiddle, you can see a working use case of table rows (along side an example with div elements).  The div elements animate properly.  The table row elements do not.

[Demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/od7kam48/7/)

**HTML**

```
<table class="animate-appear">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in repeatingItems">
    <td>{{item}}</td>
    <td>{{item}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS** (simplified)

```
table.animate-appear tr td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

table.animate-appear .ng-enter td,
table.animate-appear .ng-leave.ng-leave-active td,
table.animate-appear .ng-move td {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table.animate-appear .ng-enter.ng-enter-active td,
table.animate-appear .ng-leave td,
table.animate-appear .ng-move.ng-move-active td {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Notes:
1. The `div` elements appear to animate properly.  That is included in the fiddle for a point of comparison.
2. The table rows cannot be changed to div elements.
3. A minor timeout (as little as 30ms in my testing) causes the subsequent rows to animate properly.  **This is not a viable solution** to my issue, however.
4. I'm *only* concerned with the `ng-enter` animation.
5. I've tried applying the animation styles to the table row with no success.

Why does this happen? And more to the point, what can I do to cause all new elements in a table to animate properly?

Comment: It appears the fiddle in the example above is the 'fixed' version.  Possible to link to non-fixed? (looks like url ending with /6 is the 'broken' version)

Comment: @ryanm - the version above exhibits the wrong behavior.  Clicking "add item" adds three items: it properly animates the first entry, NOT the second entry, and animates the third entry (which has a slight timeout on it).  The fixed version is http://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/od7kam48/12/

Comment: I see now, thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The animation css for your table is causing a conflict because it is applied to both the row and the cell.  If you alter the css so that the animation applies only to the row, it should animation correctly.

```
table.animate-appear tr {
  transition: all 1s ease;
  opacity: 1;
}

table.animate-appear td {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

table.animate-appear .ng-enter,
table.animate-appear .ng-move {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
}

table.animate-appear .ng-enter.ng-enter-active,
table.animate-appear .ng-leave,
table.animate-appear .ng-move.ng-move-active {
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Here is the [update](http://jsfiddle.net/od7kam48/10/). Also I am running it in chrome. To me it looks correct, but maybe it is failing in a different way that I don't understand.

Comment: In this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/od7kam48/11/) I also updated the background color css animation to apply only to tr elements, the seem to look the same, although the div version is slower, esp on remove.

Comment: Great.  I've reduced it down to the relevant bits - if you update your code in your answer to include the right / reduced css, I'll accept.  See this fiddle for the "reduced" css: http://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/od7kam48/12/

Comment: Edited - thanks for the feedback on my feedback, I'm pretty new to stack overflow!